# Syntactical Errors in my Android media player

Tags: java, media-player, android-mediaplayer

These are my Syntactical Errors, and i don't know how to figure out,

current_song cannot be resolved to a variable

Multiple markers at this line, song_url cannot be resolved to a variable

How do i resolve the above errors. I am unable to access song_url and current_song in my methods, for instance in,

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.stop();
            ++current_song;
            mp.setDataSource(song_url[current_song]);
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

My complete code,

```
public class Jsonmedia extends Activity {
private MediaPlayer mp;
Button play, pause, next;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.jsonview);

    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);

    try {
        // Create a URL for the desired page
        URL url = new URL("http://reallifethug.webs.com/temp_list.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                url.openStream()));

        int ch, current_song = 0, EOF = -1; // end of file
        String list[];

        String str = "";
        while ((ch = in.read()) != EOF)
            str += (char) ch;
        in.close();

        list = str.split("\n");

        for (ch = 0; ch < list.length; ++ch)
            list[ch] += "\n";

        String song_name[] = new String[list.length];
        String song_url[] = new String[list.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            song_name[i] = "";
            song_url[i] = "";
            int a = 0;
            char c;

            while ((c = list[i].charAt(a++)) != ' ')
                song_name[i] += c;

            while ((c = list[i].charAt(a++)) != '\n')
                song_url[i] += c;
        }
        mp.setDataSource(song_url[current_song]);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.prepareAsync();
    play.setEnabled(false);
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            play.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.start();
        }
    });

    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.pause();
        }
    });

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.stop();
            ++current_song;
            mp.setDataSource(song_url[current_song]);
            mp.start();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.jsonmedia, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

LOG cat,
05-18 17:37:14.272: D/AndroidRuntime(486): Shutting down VM
05-18 17:37:14.272: W/dalvikvm(486): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-18 17:37:14.291: E/AndroidRuntime(486): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 17:37:14.291: E/AndroidRuntime(486): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 17:37:14.291: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at com.hiphop.streamingmediaplayer.Jsonmedia$4.onClick(Jsonmedia.java:114)
05-18 17:37:14.291: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
05-18 17:37:14.291: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
05-18 17:37:14.291: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-18 17:37:14.291: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-18 17:37:14.291: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-18 17:37:14.291: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-18 17:37:14.291: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 17:37:14.291: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-18 17:37:14.291: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-18 17:37:14.291: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-18 17:37:14.291: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-18 17:37:16.301: I/Process(486): Sending signal. PID: 486 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0):

You have `song_url` defined inside `try` block hence it is not available outside.

So declare them before `try` like :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.jsonview);

    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    int current_song = 0;
    String song_url[] = null;

    try {
    ....
    ....
    song_url = new String[list.length];
}
```

Comment: i am still getting the error, and when i click on next button my app forcefully closes

Comment: can you post what does logcat says